# Period of a circle

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let a function $\alpha:[0,2\pi n]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be such that $t\rightarrow(cost,sint)$.

I don't understand why the period of $\alpha$ is $2\pi n$.

[image]

So in my opinion it should be $2\pi$ according to this definition. Why is it $2\pi n$?

If I am correct, then why the turning number defined as such is $n$.

[image]

$$Turn[\alpha]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}1dt=1$$

Here is where the confusion comes from [image]

Comment: The period is $2 \pi$. $2 \pi n$ is the maximum value of $t$

Comment: I have edited the question because I am confused by this book... is there something wrong with their definitions of turning number or period?

Comment: Why do you think that the turning number is $n$? I cannot see the relationship

Comment: I dont think that, it is stated in the book that it is $n$.

Comment: Can you show us the fragment where they state a period $2\pi n$ ?

Comment: They do not, I concluded it from the statement that turning number is $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the text screwed up. With their definition of turning number, a curve with turning number $1$ that "repeats itself" $n$ times will still have turning number $1$. They got into this mess by trying to define their closed curve as a periodic map with domain $\Bbb R$. (And, of course, it is of no help to try to define the map on $[0,2\pi]$ as $a(\cos nt,\sin nt)$.)

Answer (score 2):

You're correct. The period of your $\alpha$ is $2\pi$.

Note, however, that the domain of $\alpha$ is pretty small compared to what it could be (all of $\mathbb R$). So $\alpha(t+c)$ will only be defined for $0\leq t \leq 2\pi n - c$.

For example, if $n=1$, the domain is $[0,2\pi]$, and $\alpha(t+2\pi)$ is only defined for $t=0$. Things like $\alpha(7\pi$) are not defined because $7\pi\notin[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Thank you, can you take a look at the definition of a turning number also? I have edited the question, because I am still confused...

Comment: You should make a new question for that instead of adding more questions into an existing post

Answer (score 1):

According to your definition, a regular curve $\alpha$ is **closed** provided there exists **at least** one strictly positive real number $c$ such that $\alpha(t) = \alpha(t + c)$ .

The function $\alpha$ is defined with some fixed $n \in \mathbb{N^*}$.

Hence you are right, the period is $2 \pi n$ with $n=1$, ie $2 \pi $ since it satisfies the definition.